# Automatically set read rights to files in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, power-automate, access-rights, automation

I have several hundreds of files that concern different people in our organisation, each should be visible only by the concerned people.

In our organisation every employee has a unique ID (EmployeeNumber), so, I would like that every time a file, named "XXXX-[something]" (XXXX-empleoyee number) is added on SharePoint content, that file automatically obtains read rights for the XXXX-Employee, and be inaccessible for others (but the SharePoint admin, of course).

Is there a way to automate that behavior, via PowerAutomate or other mechanisms?

Comment: If you have fixed format for all file names `XXXX-[something]`, you should be able to do it using Power automate flow. You want this for only one document library in site or all document libraries (existing libraries/libraries created in future) in site?

Comment: @GaneshSanap One or another solution would be OK, the main idea is that they don't see each other files, it's all. Now if there would be for all the site folders, why not